# Encapsulation in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Considering object encapsulation, should getters return an immutable property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114237/considering-object-encapsulation-should-getters-return-an-immutable-property)

Does encapsulation mandate immutability of the class?

```
Class Employee{
  private Date hireDate;
  public Date getHireDate(){
   return hireDate;
  }
}
```

In Some client Method:

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
Date temp = emp.getHireDate();
temp.setTime(...);//The Hiredate of the employee would be corrupted...
```

Answer (score 0):

No. It just means that access to the class's members is only permitted via its methods.

If you want to prevent the kind of problem you highlight, the class could return a copy of the Date object. But even then, you could provide a `setHireDate()` method and still rightly refer to the date as "encapsulated".