# Make pure immutable class

Tags: java

I have following classes :

**Emp.java**

```
final public class Emp {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Department department;

    public Emp(Integer id, String name, Department department) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.department = department;
    }

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Department.java**

```
public class Department {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public Department(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**EmployeeTest.java**

```
public class EmployeeTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Department dept1 = new Department(1, "dept1");
        Emp emp = new Emp(1, "emp1", dept1);
        emp.getDepartment().setName("dept2");
        System.out.println("emp = "+emp);

    }
}
```

Here **Emp** class is not purely an immutable class because somehow I am able to change the values of **Department** (as shown in the example).

What are the best possible changes which will make **Emp** class a pure Immutable class ?

Comment: Why do you need the setters in Department?

Comment: There might be a chances that Department class can be used at other places also... My intention is to make Emp class pure immutable, not Department.

Comment: The technique you need is called *defensive copying*. Google is at your disposal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **getters** for non-primitive field, use this structure

```
public class Line {

   private final Point start;
   private final Point end;

   public Line(final Point start, final Point end) {
       this.start = new Point(start);
       this.end = new Point(end);
   }

   public Point getStart() {
       return new Point(start);
   }

   public Point getEnd() {
       return new Point(end);
   }
}
```

So, simply create new instance of department that is equals to previous

P.S. In my example you can see pure immutable class
**EDIT:**
Also you can add to Department class copy-contructor

```
public Department(final Department dep)  
{ ... }
```

And to Employer

```
getDepartment()  
{  
   return new Department(department);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like removing setters and do initialization in a constructor, you can think about returning immutable (from the point of view of the `Emp` class) objects, which will web objects' copies, in getters (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/128712/1579085).

```
final public class Emp {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Department department;

    public Emp(Integer id, String name, Department department) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.department = (Department) department.clone();
    }

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return (Department) department.clone();
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And implement the method `clone()` in `Department` (which will implement the interface `Cloneable`) of course.

This approach is suitable, if you need to be able to modify `Department`, but the objects of the `Emp` class should be safe from those outer modifications.

Comment: The `Department` could still be changed in your code. You must do a copy/clone in you constructor as well.

Comment: @maba Yes, but now the `Emp` class is safe, and nobody can break its logic by altering `department`. (I'll correct my answer.)

Comment: But if I have a reference `dep`to `Department` and use that in the constructor then I can update the `Department` outside the `Emp` by doing `dep.setName("other")` and altered the `department`.

Comment: @maba In that case one can should use a copy again - in the constructor. Sorry, forgot to put in in the code.

Answer (score 1):

See Efffective Java:

Item 15: Minimize mutability – 5 rules to follow.

1. Don’t provide any methods that modify the object’s state
2. Ensure that the class can’t be extended
3. Make all fields final
4. Make all fields private
5. Ensure exclusive acess to any mutable components

Answer (score 0):

make all attributes `final`, and remove all setters

Comment: That would make all his classes immutable and that was not his intention. `Department` should be mutable.

Answer (score 0):

Implement **clone()** in Department and make **Emp** return a clone of **department** in **getDepartment()**.

If references to Department used in constructing Emp are available after construction, then Emp's constructor should clone given Department.

Comment: @Ilya I failed to notice that. This makes my answer unusable.